# Using command eas build -p android --profile preview to create build but the build doesn't have the latest changes that i made in app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo for building a React Native app.

I am using command : **eas build -p android --profile preview** from expo documentation
to make an apk file for android.

Latest i use that link provided by expo to download the apk file and install in my android device.
But when i install it, it doesn't reflect the new changes i made..

I also tried updating my versionCode and version and then typing **eas build:configure**.

My eas.json structure:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.5.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "local": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"  
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I want latest changes to reflect in lastest apk build

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem in the eas configuration setup

You can try build with expo

```
$ expo build:android
```

also i attached my eas file

```
{
 "cli": {
 "version": ">= 0.52.0"
},
"build": {
  "preview": {
    "android": {
      "buildType": "apk"
    }
 },
"preview2": {
  "android": {
    "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
  }
 },
 "preview3": {
   "developmentClient": true
  },
  "production": {}
 },
 "submit": {
  "production": {}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First,** you need to install eas cli globally using by command :

```
 npm install --global eas-cli
```

**Note: open Terminal with Administration**

then, create an account in Expo and log in to Eas account on Your local machine (in Terminal ) using the command line:

```
eas login
```

modify eas.json following the code :

```
{
  "build": {
    "androidapk": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

then run the command from project root :

```
eas build -p android --profile androidapk
```

**Note: "androidapk" is a profile name. You can define any name here.**

Thanks.